# Fixed bottom full width position buttons react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to create instagram like app at ios on react native. 
I setted a listview with pics and three buttons:

```
<View>
   <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
             dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
             renderRow={(rowData) => <TouchableHighlight onPress={(() => this.openProjectCard(rowData.cards_id, rowData.area_all))}>
                 <Image style={styles.item}
                        source={{uri: `http://romangjx.bget.ru/rubkoff_pics/p${rowData.code}/main/main.jpg`}}/>
             </TouchableHighlight>}
             initialListSize={15}/>
   <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
       <Text
           style={styles.marginHorizontal}
           onPress={this.showBelow100}
           color='#841584'>
           {(() => this.sup('<100м', '2'))()}
       </Text>
       <Text
           style={styles.marginHorizontal}
           onPress={this.showBetween100And200}
           color='#841584'>
           {(() => this.sup('100м-200м', '2'))()}
       </Text>
       <Text
           style={styles.marginHorizontal}
           onPress={this.showAbove200}
           color='#841584'>
           {(() => this.sup('>200м', '2'))()}
       </Text>
   </View>
</View>
```

there are styles :

```
t styles = StyleSheet.create({
   list: {
       justifyContent: 'center',
       flexDirection: 'row',
       flexWrap: 'wrap'
   },
   item: {
       backgroundColor: '#CCC',
       margin: 10,
       width: 100,
       height: 100
   },
   bottomBar: {
       flexDirection: 'row',


   },
   bottomButton: {
       flex: 1
   }
});
```

I had experimented a lot with flex, flexDirection, but it was wrong for me..

How can I positionate this buttons bottom fixed and make button bar full width, and three buttons inline?

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex:1` to your list and your first view. You can also add it to your buttons.

Sample:

View

```
<View style={styles.container}>
     <View style={styles.list}>
     </View>
     <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
         <Text style={styles.buttons}>Test 1</Text>
         <Text style={styles.buttons}>Test 2</Text>
         <Text style={styles.buttons}>Test 3</Text>
     </View>
</View>
```

Styles

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
  },
  list: {
       justifyContent: 'center',
       flexDirection: 'row',
       flexWrap: 'wrap',
       flex:1,
   },
   bottomBar: {
       flexDirection: 'row',
       backgroundColor:'gray',
   },
   buttons:{
     flex:1,
     textAlign:'center'
   },
});
```